# Multiple row creation with one insert query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to insert multiple row using one insert query.

My table looks like below:

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| seq_no        | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| classname     | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| classteacher  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| no_of_student | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| student_roll  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now I want to insert values in such a way that the table looks like below:

```
+--------+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| seq_no | classname | classteacher | no_of_student | student_roll |
+--------+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| 1      | physics   | a            | 02            | 01           |
| 1      | physics   | a            | 02            | 02           |
+--------+-----------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

where user doesn't have to put 'student_roll'.

Help me to find a way where using below kind of query one can get the above table:

```
insert into temp2(seq_no,classname,classteacher,no_of_student) values ('1','physics','a','02');
```

Here if no_of_student is 02 then row will be created with student_roll 01 and 02 sequentially.

I was thinking of this using for loop.

Comment: `seq_no` and `no-of-students` really should be integers not VARCHAR

Comment: And probably `student_roll` as well

Comment: Is `student_roll` supposed to be unique? I knda think it ought to be

Comment: no student_roll should not be unique. and please answer this question using '(convert(no_of_student,unsigned))' conversion. Because I can't change the data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions would typically include a table of numbers and `insert ... select` syntax.

Here is a simple solution using an explicit inline table:

```
insert into temp2(seq_no,classname,classteacher,no_of_student) 
select 1, 'physics', 'a', 2, n
from (
    select 1 n
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 5
    union all select 6
    union all select 7
    union all select 8
    union all select 9
    union all select 10
) t
```

In MySQL 8.0, if you have a table with enough records, say `other_table`, you can use `row_number()`:

```
insert into temp2(seq_no,classname,classteacher,no_of_student) 
select 1, 'physics', 'a', 2, n
from (select row_number() over(order by rand()) n from other_table) t
where n <= :number_of_records to insert
```

Note: it has been commented already by RiggsFolly that the numeric-like values should be stored as numbers, not as strings. This answer assumes that. Else, you would need to `cast()` integer values to `char`, like so:

```
insert into ...
select '1', 'physics', 'a', '2', cast(n as char)
from ...
```

Comment: Will you please consider seq_no,no_of_student,student_roll as varchar and change their data type using '(convert(no_of_student,unsigned))' and answer it again.It will be really helpful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @SanghamitraLahiri: answer updated with explicit conversion to string.

Comment: create table other_table(no_of_records int);
insert into other_table values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);   I have created a table using these code. and applied the code as you said . But this give me the below mentioned error:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(order by rand()) n from other_table) t where n <= :number_of_records to insert' at line 1

Comment: @SanghamitraLahiri: you are mixing things here. `:number_of_records` is a parameter that you should replace with the number of records that you want to generate.

Comment: But since you have created a table of numbers, you don’t need that. Just: `insert into temp2(seq_no,classname,classteacher,no_of_student) 
select '1', 'physics', 'a', '2', cast(no_of_records as char)
from othertable`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have created another table named "other_table". It hold two columns "num" and "num_explain". and the table looks like below:

```
+-----+-------------+
| num | num_explain |
+-----+-------------+
| 02  | 01          |
| 02  | 02          |
+-----+-------------+
```

Then I have used the below code to get desired result:

```
insert into temp2(seq_no,classname,classteacher,no_of_student,student_roll) select '1','physics','a',num,num_explain from other_table where num='02';
```